# Can I set my Sony A7 ISO to only use full stop settings?

Tags: camera-settings, sony-nex

The ISO on my A7 goes in 1/3 stops? e.g., 50, 64, 100. Is there any way I can change it to full stops?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I'm not seeing anything in [the user manual](https://docs.sony.com/release//ILCE-7_7R_EN.pdf) that lets you change the scale of ISO settings.  You can switch exposure compensation, shutter speed, and aperture settings to go from 1/3 stops to 1/2 stops, but I'm not seeing anything specifically for ISO.

Comment: thanks, I did went though the manual and found nothing